# Is there a relationship between reflecting/rotating over x-axis and y-axis?

Tags: functions

Let's say I am given any arbitrary function and asked to reflect it over the x-axis and the y-axis. Is there any relationship between the two new reflections?

How about if I then rotate it around the y-axis or x-axis. Is there a relationship between the volumes?

Comment: What do you mean by relationship?

Comment: @QthePlatypus Like is there a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function $y=f(x)$ then reflecting it on the y axis $y=-f(x)$ and reflecting it on the x axis $y=f(-x)$.